# [c#]Redirecting web page by just using sockets and tcp?

Tags: c#

is there such a way to do this? of course not using httpwebresponse

**p.s. i'm doing a proxy server application so once a user is not authorized to use my proxy, he'll be redirected to a webpage like " you're not authorized " or such

Comment: Don't put [tags] in the subject.  That is what the tags field is for.

Comment: Oh, would like to apologize for that.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a redirect is part of HTTP.  If your proxy server does not understand HTTP then it needs to establish some other communication protocol with the clients it is serving.  If it does understand HTTP, then it needs to issue a 302 or 303 response along with the new url to the client as defined in HTTP.